# Borders transfer animation with being visible all the time

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I've been wondering how could it be possible to implement transfer animation of borders (or box-shadow) from one element to another.
Here's raw example,

```css
    .item {
      float: left;
      width: 33.33%;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .item:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
      /* border: 3px solid black; */
    }
    .sections {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="sections">
          <ul>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Element 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Element 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Element 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

In this case "borders" is `box-shadow` or `border` in `.item:hover` class. As you can see, borders appears and destroys on hover event, but I need borders flowing from one `li` element to another `li` element without destroying, keeping being visible all the time.
I swear I've seen such thing on several web sites, could you suggest something with this one maybe with help of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you
I got this from Codepen this is not my code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 300 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding: .75rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
  height: .25rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">Uno</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">Dos</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">Tres</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">Quatro</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
</div>
```

Source: https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon

Comment: This is a nice simple way forward and gave me the idea of using the last element in the list, thanks. We can simplify it (in the sense of not needing to add another element in the HTML) by using instead a pseudo element on the last element in the list and formatting that when a li a element is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works for you

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background: #eee;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 27em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 25em;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .4em .2em;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;

  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: width .3s,right .3s;
  -moz-transition: width .3s,right .3s;
  -o-transition: width .3s,right .3s;
  transition: width .3s,right .3s;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) a { width: 4em; }
ul li:nth-child(2) a { width: 4em; }
ul li:nth-child(3) a { width: 4em; }
ul li:nth-child(4) a { width: 12em; }
ul li:nth-child(5) a { width: 5em; }

ul li:last-child a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: inherit;
    bottom: -3px;
    width: inherit;
    height: 38px;
    background: #ccc;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) ~ li:last-child a {
  right: 25em;
  width: 4em;
}

ul li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child a {
  right: 21em;
  width: 4em;
}

ul li:nth-child(3):hover ~ li:last-child a {
  right: 17em;
  width: 4em;
}

ul li:nth-child(4):hover ~ li:last-child a {
  right: 5em;
  width: 12em;
}

ul li:nth-child(5):last-child:hover a {
  right: 0;
  width: 5em;
}

ul li:hover ~ li:last-child a::after,
ul li:last-child:hover a::after { border-color: red; }

ul li:last-child a {
  min-width: 5em;
  max-width: 5em;
}

ul li a:hover,
ul li a:focus {
  color: red;
  /*transition*/
  -webkit-transition: width .3s,right .3s,background-color .3s;
  -moz-transition: width .3s,right .3s,background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: width .3s,right .3s,background-color .3s;
  transition: width .3s,right .3s,background-color .3s;
}

ul li a:focus { border-bottom: 3px solid #c351fa; }
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home </a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#"> Lorem </a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#"> Ipsum </a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#"> Lorem dummy text</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#"> Sit amet </a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a pseudo element on the last li a element to show a border as CSS lets us select the last sibling element when any element in the list is hovered.

We can then set the border color and set the right position of this pseudo element and have it transition to the hovered li a element position.

It is possible to have a fairly general solution - setting a CSS variable to the number of elements in the list (and the transition time too if wanted) and (almost) everything else falls into place using CSS calc.

However, unfortunately, although CSS has the ability in theory to let you use the n value (in nth-child(n)) this only seems to work for pseudo element content at the moment so we can't use it to do calculations.

I have therefore put in a set of nth child settings in the CSS - currently there are 6 so you can have a list of up to 6 without changing anything except for --n. If you want more then add more.

Here's the snippet.

```css
.sections ul {
  --n: 3; /* the number of items in the list */
  --t: 1s; /* the time taken to move to the new hover position */
  --w: calc(100% / var(--n)); 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* below is the original CSS */
    .item {
      float: left;
      width: var(--w);
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .item a {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .sections {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
/* end of the original CSS */

ul li:last-child a::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    right: inherit;
    width: var(--w);
    height:1.5em;
    transform: translateY(-0.3em);
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: right var(--t) ease;
}

ul li:nth-child(1):hover ~ li:last-child a {
  right: calc(var(--w) * calc(var(--n) - 1));
}

ul li:nth-child(2):hover ~ li:last-child a { /*when you hover on the second element it changes the last element's a width and its position */
   right: calc(var(--w) * calc(var(--n) - 2));
}

ul li:nth-child(3):hover a {
  right: calc(var(--w) * calc(var(--n) - 3));
}

ul li:nth-child(4):hover a {
  right: calc(var(--w) * calc(var(--n) - 4));
}

ul li:nth-child(5):hover a {
  right: calc(var(--w) * calc(var(--n) - 5));
}

ul li:nth-child(6):hover a {
  right: calc(var(--w) * calc(var(--n) - 6));
}

ul li:hover ~ li:last-child a::after,
ul li:last-child:hover a::after {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li a {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <div class="sections">
          <ul>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Element 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Element 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">Element 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```